# How do I use Clutter in conjunction with C#?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, clutter

I am desperately trying to make a very simple C# program utilizing clutter (In MonoDevelop IDE) to prove functionality but am unfamiliar with C# convention. Do I need to construct a clutter object to then reference it? Have I improperly declared it in my library? Should Clutter be my namespace rather than HelloWorld? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using Clutter;

namespace HelloWorld {
    public class HelloWorld {
        public int Main () {            

            // Init declaration produces error: 
            // Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'method group' was expected
            Clutter.Init ();

            Stage stage = Stage.Default;
            stage.Color = new Clutter.Color (0, 0, 0, 255);
            stage.SetSize (512, 512);

            stage.Show ();

            // Main declaration produces error: 
            // Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'method group' was expected
            Clutter.Main ();

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (http://www.clutter-project.org/about) - Clutter is an open source (LGPL 2.1) software library for creating fast, compelling, portable, and dynamic graphical user interfaces. It is a core part of MeeGo, and is supported by the open source community. Its development is sponsored by Intel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the *Clutter* is a class in the *Clutter* namespace

```
using System;
using Clutter;

namespace HelloWorld {
    public class HelloWorld {
        public int Main () {            

            // Init declaration produces error: 
            // Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'method group' was expected
            Clutter c = new Clutter();
            c.Init();

            Stage stage = Stage.Default;
            stage.Color = new Clutter.Color (0, 0, 0, 255);
            stage.SetSize (512, 512);

            stage.Show();

            // Main declaration produces error: 
            // Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'method group' was expected
            c.Main();

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried that as well but then it claims the variable c cannot be declared due to "Clutter c = new Clutter();" causing the error: `Clutter' is a `namespace' but a `type' was expected... which is out of my realm of understanding...

Comment: do you have a class named Clutter?

Comment: no, because clutter is just the library I'm using to create graphics with the clutter engine. so it's listed in my references in monodevelop as "clutter-sharp", being the C# binding, and is imported in my program but seems otherwise non-functional.

Comment: in that case, Clutter is just a library, and you have to use the classes in it. as I don't know the structure of this library, I can't write codes for you. refer to the API documents or take a look at what classes in this library and then decide which classes you should use to create graphics